# What causes dark brown spots on guava fruit?

Tags: fruit-trees, diseases, guavas

I am from India and I see that young guava fruits have dark black/brown spots on them. I grow them at my home. I have attached photos of the fruits. Could someone help in identifying the disease and possible treatment for the the plant and fruits?[image: Guava pic black/brown]